# How to add a text subscript to a special character in ggplot2 factor label?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axes

I need to first relabel the factors such that there is alpha symbol followed by text-subscripts. I followed a few examples from a few places and tried the following.

```
df <- data.frame(alpha = c("aii","aij","ajj","aji"), count = c(1,2,3,4))

ggplot(aes(x = alpha, y = count), data = df) + geom_points()+
    scale_x_discrete(labels=c("aii" = bquote(\u03b1 [ii]), "aij" = bquote(\u03b1 [ij]),
                              "ajj" = bquote(\u03b1 [jj]),"aji" = bquote(\u03b1 [ji]))
```

where \u03b1 is the unicode for alpha

I get `Error: unexpected input in: "aii" = bquote(\u03b1 [ii])`

Any suggestions on how to proceeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bquote()` needs quotes around the unicode, and the call to `geom_point()` is misspelled.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(alpha = c("aii","aij","ajj","aji"), count = c(1,2,3,4))

ggplot(aes(x = alpha, y = count), data = df) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("aii" = bquote("\u03b1" [ii]), "aij" = bquote("\u03b1" [ij]), 
                            "ajj" = bquote("\u03b1" [jj]),"aji" = bquote("\u03b1" [ji])))
```

[image]